# Aligning a div in the middle doesn't work

Tags: html, css, margin, text-alignment, text-align

The website: http://speelgoedwinkelxl.nl/

I can't get the bottom div aligned in the center

It is the part witch says Meld je aan voor onze nieuwsbrief

I tried to use margin: 0 auto; and text-align: center; but both doesn't work.

The code is from a Magento template but I can't find out why I cant get it centered.

```
<div class="ma-footer-static-container-bottom1">
        <div class="ma-footer-static">
            <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="social span4">
<div><div class="footer-subscribe">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>Meld je aan voor onze nieuwsbrief</span></strong>
    </div>
    <form action="http://speelgoedwinkelxl.nl/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div class="newsletter-content">
            <div class="form-subscribe-header">
                <!--<label for="newsletter"></label>-->
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
               <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="Meld je aan voor onze nieuwsbrief" class="input-text required-entry validate-email">
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="Inschrijven" class="button"><span><span></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</div>
</div>            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try this, in custom.css line 92 set width: 1121px; and in custom.css line 94 set margin-left: 275px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your containing div has only `span4` which makes it impossible for the inner div to center.

So change that to span12 and remove the custom `width`. In fact, the complete `.ma-footer .social` css declarations are not needed.

```
<div class="social span12">
    ...
</div>
```

Instead, add `width: 500px;` to `.footer-subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `float: none;` and `margin: auto;` of element `.row-fluid show-grid` (where your newsletter is in). Now it has a `float: left;` and a `margin-left: 0;`.

Comment: I have added it but it doesn't work. I also don't see the float: left on row-fluid show-grid.